# Board game state design in Clojure

Tags: sockets, tcp, clojure

I try to design a server implementation of a turn based multiplayer board game (Carcassonne) using a simple TCP networking in Clojure. For now I don't want persistent durable state (no Backend DB).
I currently see the problem to maintain game/turn state given the concurrent nature of sockets: each tcp splitters message dispatches a function which could let to arbitrary order state changes. I use an `atom` to keep the state using `swap` with a function to modify it. Although it is correct that the state is changed atomically, no global order is given. A second message of the same player or another message by another player could be processed before the first message of the actual player whose turn it is, leading to a corrupt state.

So my question is: how to maintain correct state using TCP networking in Clojure without a DB.

I'm aware similar questions about game state have been asked before but I don't think they provided an answer for my case.

Comment: You simply don't allow another player to make a move. Each client receives a message from the server when it is allowed to make a move and then sends its move to the server.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) says that " TCP provides reliable, *ordered* and error-checked delivery ... ". So you *can* process messages that come through the same socket in order.